# Retrieve 2 substrings from string

Tags: php, string, substring

I have tried substr and split, but I can't figure out how to get this data parsed.

```
$string = 'aDetails.push(new Array("XADP10520", "XADP10520 - ec Example Title"));';

//$label = 'XADP10520';

//$title = 'Example Title';
```

Comment: So why is `$title` equal to just `Example Title` and not the full string `XADP10520 - ec Example Title` as in the example?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This looks like an attempt to parse javascript in php, which just does not make sense.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Maybe because `XADP10520` is the label and should not be part of the title. Then starting a title with `-` might be weird.

Comment: @LoganMurphy but obviously in JS (which the string appears to be) it is part of the title. And if it is not, what about the `- ec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a basic regex to extract both parts with `preg_match()`.
Here's an example :

```
$string = 'aDetails.push(new Array("XADP10520", "XADP10520 - ec Example Title"));';

preg_match('/\("(?<label>.+)", "\1 - ec (?<title>.+)"\)/i', $string, $parts);

$label = $parts['label'];
$title = $parts['title'];

echo $label; // XADP10520
echo $title; // Example Title
```

Please note I assumed both keys to be the same, and the `- ec` part to be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but something like this should work:

```
<?php
$string = 'aDetails.push(new Array("XADP10520", "XADP10520 - ec Example Title"));';
$tmps   = explode('"', $string);   //NOT SPLIT.. DEPRECATED
$label  = $tmps[1];
$title  = str_replace($label.' - ec ','',$tmps[3]);
?>
```

Not tested and the code is pretty much useless except for this specific example, but it should work